# How to assign a value to each member of a group if one member meets criteria in R

Tags: r

I have some census data about different households, like so (obviously the real dataset is much larger, with lots of additional variables):

```
df <- data.frame("HouseholdID" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
                 "Age" = c(45, 38, 6, 78, 64, 56, 58, 12))
```

I'm interested in knowing whether or not each adult has kid(s) under the age of 18, so I thought the easiest approach might be to add a column to the data frame:

```
df$kid_under_18 <- "No"
```

and then change the value to "Yes" for rows that meet my criteria.  The trouble is that I'm having trouble writing the R code that says:

> "for each HouseholdID, if any Age < 18"  <- "Yes"

I think I should be able to do this using "by" (i.e. look by HouseholdID) and an "if any" statement, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to change the value of my "kid_under_18" column based on this.  I think I'm getting close-ish, but the syntax just isn't there yet:

`by(df$Age, df$HouseholdID, function(x)  if(any(x < 18)) {df$kid_under_18 <- "Yes"})`  will evaluate the statement, but not put anything in the data frame.

`df$kid_under_18 <- by(df$Age, df$HouseholdID, function(x)  if(any(x < 18)) print ("Yes"))`  gives me an Error in

> `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "kid_under_18", value = list(`1` = "Yes",  :
>   replacement has 3 rows, data has 8

Comment: Try `ave()`, and you should have an `else` to cover the NULLs `ave(df$Age, df$HouseholdID, FUN = function(x)  if(any(x < 18)) "Yes" else "No")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, kid_under_18 := any(Age < 18) , HouseholdID]
```

Or if we need the 'Yes' or 'No' tage

```
setDT(df)[, kid_under_18 := c("Yes", "No")[any(Age < 18) + 1] , HouseholdID]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using library `dplyr`, you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(HouseholdID) %>% 
    mutate(under_18 = any(Age < 18))
```

Output is as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: HouseholdID [3]

  HouseholdID   Age under_18
        <dbl> <dbl>    <lgl>
1           1    45     TRUE
2           1    38     TRUE
3           1     6     TRUE
4           2    78    FALSE
5           2    64    FALSE
6           3    56     TRUE
7           3    58     TRUE
8           3    12     TRUE
```

You can use `summarise` instead of `mutate` above, if you want one row per `HouseholdID`. You can also convert logical values to something else using `ifelse` assignment within mutate as for example:

```
df %>%
   group_by(HouseholdID) %>% 
   mutate(under_18 = ifelse(any(Age < 18), 'Y', 'N'))
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for a summarizing?

```
library(plyr);
ddply(df, "HouseholdID", summarise, hasChildUnder18 = any(Age < 18))

  HouseholdID hasChildUnder18
1           1            TRUE
2           2           FALSE
3           3            TRUE
```

We can recode the `TRUE` and `FALSE` as `yes` and `no`:

```
library(plyr); library(car);
ddply(df, "HouseholdID", summarise, hasChildUnder18 = recode(any(Age < 18), 
                                                     "TRUE='yes'; FALSE='no'"))

  HouseholdID hasChildUnder18
1           1             yes
2           2              no
3           3             yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `ifelse()` and use `cbind.data.frame()` along with `table()` function to see frequency

```
  > df$kid_under_18 <- ifelse(df$Age < 18,"Yes","No")
  > df
  #      HouseholdID Age kid_under_18
  # 1              1  45           No
  # 2              1  38           No
  # 3              1   6          Yes
  # 4              2  78           No
  # 5              2  64           No
  # 6              3  56           No
  # 7              3  58           No
  # 8              3  12          Yes

> table(cbind.data.frame(df$HouseholdID,df$kid_under_18))
#                 df$kid_under_18
# df$HouseholdID      No Yes
#              1      2   1
#              2      2   0
#              3      2   1
```